# CI Post to Controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, activerecord

I am having a bit of a nightmare with a CI build today and I am hoping that the clever stck community can bail me out :)

I have a model, view and controller named `comment_m.php (model)`, `comment_v.php (view)` and `comment.php (controller)` in CI installation.

The issue I am facing is that it doesn't seem to be getting inside the controller method and therefore is not inserting to the database.

The `URL` of the page is `http://localhost/comment/1234` if that makes any difference, for some reason I am not getting any errors and when I try and use `log_message()` it is not writing.

Can anyone see anything obvious or indeed stupid that I am doing here which could be causing the problems?

The code

---

`PHP / HTML`

```
<?php
$cattributes = array('id' => 'newComment', 'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data");
echo form_open('comment/saveComment', $cattributes);
?>
 <ul class="pull-left nav navbar-nav bar-buttons">
  <li class="camera-button" id="c_cancelLi">
   <a href="#cancel" title="Cancel this action" id="c_cancelBtn"><?=lang('board.cancel-btn');?></a>
  </li>
  <li class="link-button" id="c_photoLi">
   <input class="btn btn-default" id="c_ImgBtn" name="cmmt_image" type="file" class="filestyle">
  </li>
  <li class="link-button" id="c_linkLi"><a href="#link" title="Post a link" id="cLinkBtn"><span class="btn-icon btn-icon-link"></span></a></li>
 </ul>
 <textarea style="display: none" name="cmmt_text" id="c_cmmt_text"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_location_name" id="c_cmmt_location_name" value="PASS Online">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_latitude" id="c_cmmt_latitude" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_longitude" id="c_cmmt_longitude" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_user_id" id="c_cmmt_user_id" value="<?=$user_id;?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_type" id="c_cmmt_type" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_link" id="c_cmmt_link" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_link_title" id="c_cmmt_link_title" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmmt_post_id" value="<?=$pid;?>"/>
 <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav bar-buttons">
  <li class="send-button">
   <input type="submit" class="je-send_button" id="cmmtSendPost" value="<?=lang('board.send');?>">
  </li>
 </ul>
 <section class="gap">&nbsp;</section>
<?php
echo form_close();
?>
```

`JQuery`

```
$('#newComment').submit(function(cmmts) {
    //$('#hud-overlay').show();
    var comment = $('#cmmtTextEntry').html();
    $('#c_cmmt_text').val(comment);
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "HTML",
        processData:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
    cmmts.preventDefault(); //Prevent Default action.
    //f.unbind();
});
```

`Controller`

```
public function saveComment($_POST) {
    $postId = $_POST['cmmt_post_id'];
    $type = $_POST['cmmt_type'];
    if($type == 0) {
        $this->comment_m->commentThought($_POST);
        redirect('board');
    } elseif($type == 1) {
        //image
        $this->comment_m->cmmtImage($_POST);
        log_message('info', 'inside of cmmt if type 1.');
        redirect('comment/'.$postId);
    } elseif($type == 3) {
        //link
        $this->comment_m->cmmtLink($_POST);
        log_message('info', 'inside of cmmt if type 3.');
        redirect('comment/'.$postId);
    } else {
        log_message('info', 'inside of cmmt if else just returning.');
        return;
    }
}
```

`Model`

```
public function commentThought() {
    $media = $this->input->post('cmmt_user_id').'-'.substr($sha1,0,25).'.jpg';
    $now = microtime(true);
    $cmmtText = $this->input->post('cmmt_text');
    //Regex Functions
    $p1 = '~<span contenteditable=\\"false\\" class=\\"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-@\\">|<span contenteditable=\\"false\\" class=\\"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#\\">|</span>|<span>|<span contenteditable=\\"false\\">|&nbsp;~';
    $r1 = '';
    $start = preg_replace($p1, $r1, $cmmtText);
    $users = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"user\" class=\"userHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>$2|$3</_link> ", $start);
    $tags = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"tag\" class=\"tagHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)#(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>tag://$3|#$3</_link> ", $users);
    $last = preg_replace("~(^|\\s)#(\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)~", " <_link>tag://$2|#$2</_link> ", $tags);
    //End

    $data = array(
        'cmmt_type' => 0,
        'cmmt_post_id' => $this->input->post('cmmt_post_id'),
        'cmmt_user_id' => $this->input->post('cmmt_user_id'),
        'cmmt_latitude' => $this->input->post('cmmt_latitude'),
        'cmmt_longitude' => $this->input->post('cmmt_longitude'),
        'cmmt_location_name' => $this->input->post('cmmt_location_name'),
        'cmmt_text' => $last,
        'cmmt_media_url' => $media,
        'cmmt_deleted' => 0,
        'cmmt_updated' => $now,
        'cmmt_posted_date' => $now,
        'cmmt_language_id' => 1,
    );

    $this->db->insert('PAS_Comment', $data);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If your Controller is not getting hit, you may have a routing problem.

If your Class/Method are spelt incorrectly, or don't relate to actual
naming conventions, use the route file to make one.

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['comment/save'] = 'class/method';
```

---

### Error Reporting

Inside **application/config/confg.php**, make sure your messages are enabled(development mode only)

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

---

### Enctype

Save you some steps, use `form_open_multipart('comment/save', array('id'=>''))`

---

### Accessing Inputs($_POST,$_GET,$_FILE)

Use the Input library `$this->input->post` as it will retrieve the Globals for you and at a very basic level sanitize the input fields for you if you have XSS enabled.

---

### Form Validation

Always validate user inputs, even if they are **admins**.
Again never use Globals such as `$_POST`, The input library will somewhat protect
against `XSS`, however if your field is an integer type, validate it as one with the `form_validation` library.

Comment: Awesome!!! thanks man that is the most well rounded answer I think I have ever had, I really appreciate the pointers and solution.